# Play Framework JsNumber argument converted to type Any

Tags: scala, playframework

```
    val c: Option[Int] = None
    val temp = c.getOrElse(0)
    play.api.libs.json.JsNumber( temp )            //1
    play.api.libs.json.JsNumber( c.getOrElse(0) )  //2
```

Why does 1 compile, while 2 gives type mismatch (found: Any, required: BigDecimal)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `JsNumber` expects `BigDecimal`, when you have your `temp` infered to be an `Int`, implicit conversion changes it to `BigDecimal` and it works.

When you say

```
JsNumber(c getOrElse 0)
```

in a place where `BigDecimal` is expected, my guess is `0` is converted to `BigDecimal` to match argument type

```
JsNumber(c getOrElse BigDecimal(0))
```

But signature of `getOrElse` says

```
getOrElse[B >: A](default: ⇒ B): B
```

The most specific common supertype of `Int` and `BigDecimal` is `Any`. The call looks more or less like this:

```
JsNumber((None: Option[Int]) getOrElse (BigDecimal(0): Any))
```

And that results in passing `Any` where `BigDecimal` is expected.

Possible solution is to annotate the type yourself

```
JsNumber((c getOrElse 0) : Int)
```

or use `BigDecimal` instead of `Int`

```
JsNumber((None: Option[BigDecimal]) getOrElse 0)
```

Comment: I had expected it to first use the type of the getOrElse argument if it has one (which it does here) to deduce the type B, and then see if that works as the argument to JsNumber, which it would have with an implicit conversion of Int to BigDecimal. It seem odd that it would first try to force B to be BigDecimal, which is not allowed since A is Int, and then end up with something that doesn't work. I was unable to find a description of precise type deduction rules for these cases. Can anyone provide a link?